# Programming function that is dependent on two files

Tags: r, function, file-io

I have a function in R that is dependent on two files with the same name but different extensions such as a.xxx and a.yyy. I need to read both files into memory to manipulate them

I need this function to be applicable to a folder of like 1000 pairs of files where each pair has the same name where one has extension .xxx and other has .yyy.

How can I program it so the user can use some kind of apply function across all the files instead of calling the function 1000 times.
Right now I have the function basically like this (in pseudocode):

```
sampleFunction<-function(){
     a<-a.xxx
     b<-a.yyy
...
}
```

If it only relied on a single file, I can make a list of all file names in that folder and do lapply but how would I do it if the function relies on two files?

Comment: First, your function should take the base filename, and then append the different extensions. Perhaps `sampleFunction <- function(basefn) { ... }`. Perhaps your first file would be based on `file1 <- paste0(basefn, ".ext1")`.

Comment: From there, use `file.exists(file1) && file.exists(file2)` to make sure both exist before doing something with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood your question/case, this may help:

```
  sampleFunction<-function(.folderpath, .filename){

    # getting files inside the specific folderpath
    files <- list.files(.folderpath, full.names = T)

    # find matching files
    file_matches <- files[str_detect(files, .filename)]

    # returning both files
    return(file_matches)
   }
```

Of course, you can read the files inside the function, if that's preferred:

```
  sampleFunction<-function(.folderpath, .filename){

    # getting files inside the specific folderpath
    files <- list.files(.folderpath, full.names = T)

    # find matching files
    file_matches <- files[str_detect(files, .filename)]

    # returning both files
    for (i in 1:length(file_matches){

      # for example .RDS files
      readRDS(file_matches[i])
    }
   }
```

This approach may not work if your case is a little different than I understand it.